# Event driven Client Server in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, wcf, callback, client-server

I followed the following tutorial for a chat application:
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWPFChat.aspx?msg=3513805

It creates a WCF server with callbacks. The most interesting part for me is the broadcast message to all clients, when a new client logs on.

I Would like to create the same application but with a java client. As far as I understand, the WCF callback mechanism is not supported in Java? Has anyone an idea how I can achieve the same functionality with a Java client?

Comment: for people like me who are not familiar with WCF, can you mention the underlying protocol that WCF is using? For example if you ask how to do websocket in java, you might get some answers. The question may still be out of scope of this forum.

Comment: I am not sure which protocol the WCF service is using, I just followed the tutorial. The service binding says: binding="netTcpBinding", bindingConfiguration="DuplexBinding".

Comment: To be clear, I am not hooked on WCF, I just want a client server application with a C# server and a Java client. I liked the idea where the server can broadcast messages to the clients, but I am not sure how to do this